# How can I kill a process triggered by the MySQL event scheduler?

Tags: mysql

I have an NP-hard data transformation problem that I know can run for hours. So I'm fine tuning some heuristics to keep the complexity under control.

But the process may take 5 minutes to run with one setting and 10 hours with an adjustment of 20% on just one parameter. As this also depends on the actual data.

I would like to stop the process if it is running for too long. This is both in regular operation as well as when I trigger the event manually.

The idea was to track the `show processlist`, identify this event and kill it if it's been running over 15 minutes. Unfortunately I don't seem to see any running process from the event - even though I can see log entries written at the same time.

How can I kill a process fired by the event scheduler?

I'm using MySQL 5.7 on CentOS.

Comment: Are you using the `root` MySQL account when you run `show processlist`?

Comment: Ah the events guy. I might need to get some of my event code to you (your prior question). An event starts a thread, so there is no process here. Best to architect it with it own self awareness of its start time (and `now()`). That is easy to accomplish. Then during its peeks at its duration, have it fall out if it runs too long.

Comment: This assumes the whole thing is not blocked on one call (like a massive update with a join pattern or something that is thrashing at innodb). I wrote a few Event answers seen on my profile page. Perhaps the Performance one could be used. It logs activity as it runs to allow for reporting of performance. So in between steps, have it not continue to the next step. Each step could be surrounded with `IF bContinue THEN` ... a boolean check

Comment: Running events **are** in the processlist... but you need the `SUPER` or `PROCESS` privilege in order to see it.  Named locks are also useful for handling event concurrency by preventing parallel startups.  `IF GET_LOCK('some lock name',0) IS NOT TRUE THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'failed to acquire lock'; END IF;`.  The exception kills the new invocation of the event and gets written to the MySQL error log file.  The lock is automatically released when the event finishes, since each invocation of each event runs in a unique "client" thread that cleans up after itself.

Comment: The question is not about parallelism but of event running time @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: @Drew, you're right... but sometimes there's a real question lurking behind the question that was asked, and that seemed like a possibility here, since the event scheduler has no built in concurrency protection.  I've seen many devs get tripped up by frequently-scheduled events that wreak havoc by unexpectedly running on top of themselves.  But the first part of my comment is directly relevant to the question of record -- running events *are* in the processlist if you have permission to see them.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot True, but one wouldn't clobber them. They should die a graceful death and they could be self-aware :p

Comment: Apologise for the late resonses 1) yes - I've used root 2) Drew I've reached out via email. Everything is using `READ UNCOMMITTED` in select queries. There may be concurrent writes but for manual testing only one job was triggered at any time anyway. 3) I've used a user with all rights for everything then getting the process list.